# This Error won't go away "Illegal char <:> at index 43: com.cmplay.tiles2.app-mergeDebugResources-6:/values/values.xml"

Tags: java, android

While building signed apk this error keeps coming

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
   > Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile values resource file C:\gradels\new one\app\build\intermediates\incremental\debug\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml. Cause: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 43: com.cmplay.tiles2.app-mergeDebugResources-6:/values/values.xml). Check logs for more details
```

and on checking line "43" in values.xml it consists of this code and the values.xml cannot be edited is it generated

```
<item>269,KM</item>
```

and when I searchedd for this code in the directory it lead me to arrays.xml line no.43
which contained the same code

```
<item>269,KM</item>
```

Here's my android manifest file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:versionCode="30100715" android:versionName="3.1.0.715" android:installLocation="auto" package="com.cmplay.tiles2" platformBuildVersionCode="26" platformBuildVersionName="8.0.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="30"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x20000"/>
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.umonistudio.tile.permission.AIDL_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
    <meta-data android:name="CMPLAY_SYNC_IPC" android:value="com.cmplay.kinfoc.sync"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/app_logo" android:name="com.cmplay.tile2.GameApp" android:allowBackup="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:supportsRtl="true" android:fullBackupContent="@xml/vungle_backup_rule">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value="@string/google_app_id"/>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.cmplay.tile2.ui.LoveShareActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.cmplay.tile2.ui.ChristmasShareActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:name="com.cmplay.tile2.ui.SongMixShareActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:name="com.vungle.warren.ui.VungleActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:configChanges="smallestScreenSize|screenSize|screenLayout|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:name="com.vungle.warren.ui.VungleFlexViewActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:configChanges="smallestScreenSize|screenSize|screenLayout|orientation|keyboardHidden" android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>
        <activity android:name="com.sina.weibo.sdk.component.WeiboSdkBrowser" android:exported="false" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:exported="false" android:configChanges="smallestScreenSize|screenSize|uiMode|screenLayout|orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"/>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.cmplay.tiles2.wxapi.WXEntryActivity" android:exported="true"/>
        <provider android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" android:exported="true" android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1635899819990716"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.AutoLogAppEventsEnabled" android:value="false"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.AdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled" android:value="false"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id_gp"/>
        <activity android:name="com.applovin.adview.AppLovinInterstitialActivity" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"/>
        <activity android:name="com.applovin.adview.AppLovinConfirmationActivity" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"/>
        <meta-data android:name="applovin.sdk.key" android:value="UdAAPq-zrVhcaaKovlmPEn8qXmrUnzGFbRP_FOz5uehTE0G7l0X-nfpJPepBc3QCVrClEAr7qWa2XsAHshGdM4"/>
        <meta-data android:name="applovin.sdk.verbose_logging" android:value="false"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mopub.common.privacy.ConsentDialogActivity" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mopub.common.MoPubBrowser" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubActivity" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidActivity" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.RewardedMraidActivity" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidVideoPlayerActivity" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.cmplay.webview.ui.WebViewActivity" android:exported="true" android:process=":web" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation"/>
        <activity android:theme="@style/dialog" android:name="com.cmplay.tile2.ui.TipsGetGiftSuccedDialog" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"/>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:name="com.cmplay.internalpush.ui.OpenScreenActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
        <provider android:name="com.cmplay.webview.ipc.WebIpcProvider" android:exported="false" android:process=":web" android:authorities="com.cmplay.tiles2.ipc.web"/>
        <receiver android:name="com.appsflyer.MultipleInstallBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.cmplay.tile2.CMCampaignTrackingReceiver" android:exported="true" android:process=":service">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.cmplay.webview.broadcast.WebBroadcast" android:exported="true" android:process=":web">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.cmplay.webview.broadcast.webbroadcast"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.cmplay.webview.broadcast.GameBroadcast" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.cmplay.webview.broadcast.gamebroadcast"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.cmplay.notification.EnergyReceiver" android:exported="true" android:process=":service">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.cmplay.notification.EnergyReceiver"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <meta-data android:name="UMENG_APPKEY" android:value="55a86f6667e58e298100016b"/>
        <meta-data android:name="UMENG_CHANNEL" android:value="gp"/>
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" android:exported="true" android:process=":service">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                <category android:name="gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.cmplay.gcmPush.MyGcmListenerService" android:exported="false" android:process=":service">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.cmplay.gcmPush.MyInstanceIDListenerService" android:exported="false" android:process=":service">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.cmplay.gcmPush.RegistrationIntentService" android:exported="false" android:process=":service"/>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.ads.AudienceNetworkActivity" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
        <activity android:name="com.ironsource.sdk.controller.ControllerActivity" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation" android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" android:name="com.ironsource.sdk.controller.InterstitialActivity" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation" android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" android:name="com.ironsource.sdk.controller.OpenUrlActivity" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation" android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>
        <activity android:name="io.display.sdk.DioActivity" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:name="io.display.sdk.DioTranslucentActivity" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"
            tools:ignore="MissingClass" />
        <activity android:name="io.display.sdk.device.PermissionsHandler"/>
        <meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.33"/>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="cocos2dcpp"/>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.cmplay.tile2.ui.AppActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="layoutDirection|screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden|locale">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="fb.me"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="piano2"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.cmplay.tile2.ui.ShareActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="layoutDirection|screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden|locale"/>
        <activity android:theme="@style/dialog" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.cmplay.tile2.ui.GameProblemActivity" android:process=":service" android:taskAffinity="com.gameproblem" android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:theme="@style/dialog2" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.cmplay.exitpopup.GameExitPopupActivity" android:process=":service" android:taskAffinity="com.gameexit" android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.cmplay.util.crop.CropImageActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="layoutDirection|orientation|locale"/>
        <service android:name="com.cmplay.tile2.ui.ReportService" android:process=":service"/>
        <receiver android:name="com.cmplay.util.ConnectionChangedReceiver" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.cmplay.notification.NotificationDeleteReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:process=":service"/>
        <provider android:name="com.cmplay.ipc.IpcProvider" android:exported="false" android:process=":service" android:authorities="com.cmplay.tiles2.ipc_provider"/>
        <provider android:name="com.cmplay.tile2.NullProvider" android:exported="false" android:authorities="com.cmplay.tiles2.null_provider"/>
        <service android:name="com.cmplay.tile2.export.DumpReportService" android:exported="true" android:process=":crashReport"/>
        <meta-data android:name="SET_PROMOTION_LOG" android:value="false"/>
        <service android:name="com.cmplay.internalpush.InnerPushService" android:process=":service"/>
        <provider android:name="com.cmplay.base.util.ipc.IpcProvider" android:exported="false" android:process=":service" android:authorities="com.cmplay.tiles2.innerpush_provider"/>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:name="com.cmplay.internalpush.ui.OpenScreenVideoActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:name="com.cmplay.internalpush.ui.InsertScreenActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:name="com.cmplay.internalpush.video.IncentiveVideoPlayActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden" android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:name="com.cmplay.internalpush.video.VideoAdDetailActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
        <receiver android:name="com.cmplay.base.util.webview.broadcast.GameBroadcast" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.cmplay.base.util.webview.broadcast.gamebroadcast"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.cmplay.base.util.notify.NotifyReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.cmplay.base.util.notify"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <provider android:name="com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider" android:exported="false" android:authorities="com.cmplay.tiles2.FacebookInitProvider"/>
        <receiver android:name="com.facebook.CurrentAccessTokenExpirationBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ACTION_CURRENT_ACCESS_TOKEN_CHANGED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:theme="@style/com_facebook_activity_theme" android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:configChanges="screenSize|screenLayout|orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"/>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabMainActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"/>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:name="com.cmplay.tiles2_cn.wxapi.WXEntryActivity" android:exported="true"/>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:name="com.cmplay.tiles2_cn.baidu.wxapi.WXEntryActivity" android:exported="true"/>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:name="com.cmplay.tiles2_cn.m4399.wxapi.WXEntryActivity" android:exported="true"/>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:name="com.cmplay.tiles2_cn.uc.wxapi.WXEntryActivity" android:exported="true"/>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:name="com.tencent.tmgp.tiles2.wxapi.WXEntryActivity" android:exported="true"/>
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.VERSION" android:value="26.1.0"/>
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false"/>
        <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false"/>
        <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsJobService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false"/>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity" android:exported="false"/>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity" android:exported="false" android:excludeFromRecents="true"/>
        <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.RevocationBoundService" android:permission="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.permission.REVOCATION_NOTIFICATION" android:exported="true"/>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:name="com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|smallestScreenSize|screenSize|uiMode|screenLayout|orientation|navigation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|touchscreen|locale|mnc|mcc" android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:name="com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitTransparentActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|smallestScreenSize|screenSize|uiMode|screenLayout|orientation|navigation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|touchscreen|locale|mnc|mcc" android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:name="com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitTransparentSoftwareActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|smallestScreenSize|screenSize|uiMode|screenLayout|orientation|navigation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|touchscreen|locale|mnc|mcc" android:hardwareAccelerated="false"/>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:name="com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitSoftwareActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|smallestScreenSize|screenSize|uiMode|screenLayout|orientation|navigation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|touchscreen|locale|mnc|mcc" android:hardwareAccelerated="false"/>
        <service android:name="com.cmplay.crashreport.CrashReportService" android:process=":crashReport"/>
        <receiver android:name="com.cmplay.crashreport.WifiStateReceiver" android:process=":crashReport">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.notifications.internal.activity.CardActivity" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"/>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:name="com.aiming.mdt.sdk.ad.videoad.VideoActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="user" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:name="com.aiming.mdt.sdk.ad.interstitialAd.InterstitialActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:name="com.aiming.mdt.sdk.ad.interactivead.InteractiveActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:name="com.aiming.mdt.sdk.ad.AdtWebActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="screenSize|keyboardHidden"/>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:name="com.aiming.mdt.sdk.extra.HelpActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
        <activity android:name="com.vungle.warren.ui.VungleWebViewActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:configChanges="smallestScreenSize|screenSize|screenLayout|orientation|keyboardHidden"/>
        <receiver android:name="com.vungle.warren.NetworkStateReceiver" android:enabled="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

and build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.cmplay.tiles2'
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 30100715
    versionName "3.1.0.715"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
lint {
    abortOnError false
}

}

dependencies {
    def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version"
    //noinspection GradleCompatible,GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    // some dependenciesdseee
}
```

Comment: @akarnokd here <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="CountryCodes">

Comment: Your filename is incorrect: `com.cmplay.tiles2.app-mergeDebugResources-6:/values/values.xml`, there is a `:` after 6.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think Android will see a filename that contains a `:` as a valid filename.  Can you call the file something else?

Comment: @akarnokd Where should I search for that file I pressed ctrl+shift+n  but It didn;t showed up

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Where should I rename it I mean where is that file

Comment: This is a generated file folks, not one that @Iron11 created. Any solution to this? I came up with the same problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Illegal char <:> at index 40: com.recognize.app-mergeDebugResources-33:/values/values.xml)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72360620/illegal-char-at-index-40-com-recognize-app-mergedebugresources-33-values-v)

Answer (score -1):

check all your xml files in the res directory where you have wrongfully entered an <:> character

Comment: I searched for "<:>" in the whole project there was nothing

Comment: you can try Invalidate and restart cache then see if it works

Comment: Same error again..