# Error "Illegal char <:> at index 43: com.cmplay.tiles2.app-mergeDebugResources-6:/values/values.xml"

Tags: java, android

I got this error and when I tries to find "`com.cmplay.tiles2.app-mergeDebugResources-6:/values/values.xml).`" by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + N or CTRL + SHIFT + F it shows no file by that name .. When I searched for line 43 as shown in the error "index 43" it says

`<item>269,KM</item>` in values.xml file and the file generated and cannot be edited and when I searched for the elsewhere it showed up in arrays.xml at the same line as in values.xml `<item>269,KM</item>` Here's the start of the arrays.xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="CountryCodes">
```

I also tried finding <:> as shown in the error but no results by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + F OR CTRL + SHIFT +  N

--

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
   > Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile values resource file C:\gradels\new one\app\build\intermediates\incremental\debug\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml. Cause: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 43: com.cmplay.tiles2.app-mergeDebugResources-6:/values/values.xml). Check logs for more details.
```

Comment: But there is no such file as com.cmplay.tiles2.app-mergeDebugResources-6:/values/values.xml

Comment: Why are you posting this again? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72727512/this-error-wont-go-away-illegal-char-at-index-43-com-cmplay-tiles2-app-me

Comment: @akarnokd I tried to explain it again but with all the things that I tried with the previous answers and with more clues about the problem

Comment: Why not update your question there?

Comment: @akarnokd did but new responses